# Trigger content action from custom action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

We have som recipes that will be exposed on Google home through a [Recipe Content Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/recipes)

I would like to extend the functionality by adding a custom action that can do e.g. more advanced search to find a recipe, and then present the recipe to the user:

```
User: "Give me a recipe with tomatoes and mozzarella from MyRecipeAction"
```

Would it be possible use the Recipe Action to present the recipe from within  our custom action? Or would this require us to write the whole logic for presenting and navigating the recipe ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer from the Dialogflow support team, it turns out this is *not possible*.

Answer from Dialogflow:

> Unfortunately, it's not possible to use the Recipe Action to present
>   the recipe from within your custom action. You need to create a new
>   conversational app and write the whole logic for presenting and
>   navigating the recipe yourselves.